# Viewing SQL queries from all sources

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I found this picture in a document. It shows the queries running on a given SQL database. It looks similar to DBeaver software. However, I couldn't find a way to get to this screen from DBeaver. Can someone please help me to figure out what software this is? It would be really helpful to troubleshoot performance-related issues.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a mysql qry:  SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST. You could try it in any IDE.  You always can get your qrys and if your user has the privilegies... from other users and dbs too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's MySQL's `SHOW PROCESSLIST`.

`IN ( SELECT ... )` often optimizes poorly; try to rewrite using a `JOIN`.

This may help:

```
INDEX(status, Calendar_Date, Date_Received)
```

For more help we need to see the queries and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  You can obfuscate the names, but don't make it too hard to read.

{The `TIMESTAMP` qualifier is not required.)

Frameworks (eg, DBeaver) are handy for getting started.  But ultimately you need to understand the underlying database.