# Getting/logging a list of previously run SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database, dbeaver

From [this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71965547/viewing-sql-queries-from-all-sources/71975972#71975972) I learned that I can use `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` to get a list of active queries. But the query disappears after running the query. Is there a way to list the previously run queries or to some log files when a query is running?

Note - I'm using DBeaver to view queries using `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`

Answer (score 4):

The [query manager](https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Query-Manager/) helps you in this case. Go to "Window/ Show View/ Query Manager" or select it from the drop-down menu beside transaction options in the main toolbar.

[image]

Comment: I looked into this, looks like query manager only shows queries run by DBeaver. I need to see the history of queries run by other applications

Answer (score 0):

I found this works for a MariaDB instance so it might work for whatever MySQL you're using.

There is a logging feature that can be setup and enabled for the DB to log out all queries executed. Here is a link I found and then copied below are the steps.

First connect to your DB in DBeaver. Then run the following statements to enable logging.

```
SET GLOBAL general_log_file ='/var/log/mysql/mycustom.log';
SET GLOBAL log_output = 'FILE';
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "general_log%";
```

What you will end up with is a file `mycustom.log` under `var/log/mysql/` with every query that was ran against the DB.

Adapted from:  https://gist.github.com/joseluisq/40ec9169669aa1848492141fa6f57fcb